# Flutter: Information from database only show after code save/hot reload

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

A few subpages in my app do not display the content from the database right away. They show the content after I save the content (hot reload) though.

There are just a few subpages in my app I notice this behaviour though, and all of them have something in common: The display information from the database.

I implemented a few print statements in my code which print the information I receive from the datatabase though. So, it can not be due to a lack of information/information not received yet.

Do you have an idea on how to fix it?

Code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nutritious/custom_widgets/AppBar_Custom.dart';
import 'package:nutritious/custom_widgets/AppBar_SearchIcon.dart';
import 'package:nutritious/datenbank/firestore.dart';

import 'package:nutritious/custom_widgets/AppBar_ProfileIcon.dart';

class Krankheiten extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _KrankheitenState createState() => _KrankheitenState();
}

class _KrankheitenState extends State<Krankheiten> {
  _KrankheitenState();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    /*username.dispose();
    password.dispose();
    super.dispose();*/
  }

  List<String> krankheit_name = [];
  List<String> krankheit_beschreibung = [];

  getKrankheiten() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("krankheiten")
        .orderBy("name")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
              snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
                krankheit_name.add(doc.data()["name"]);
                krankheit_beschreibung.add(doc.data()["beschreibung"]);
              })
            });

    for (int i = 0; i < krankheit_name.length; i++) {
      print("+++");
      print(krankheit_name.length);
      print(krankheit_name[i]);
      print(krankheit_beschreibung[i]);
    }
  }

  Container createKrankheiten(int i) {
    return Container(
      width: 500,
      color: Colors.white,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 15),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15),
        child: Text(krankheit_name[i],
            textAlign: TextAlign.left, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getKrankheiten();

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBarCustom(widgetTitle: "Krankheiten"),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(218, 243, 186, 1),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      for (int i = 0; i < krankheit_name.length; i++)
                        createKrankheiten(i)
                    ],
                  ),
                ))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getKrankheiten` function is called in `build` method but it doesn't load data synchronously. So data ends up being fetched AFTER the screen is built and the screen doesn't update post fresh data fetch.

You should use a `FutureBuilder` for this:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 3):

**Two mistakes.**

1. It is because you are not `awaiting` for the future function `getKrankheiten()`.
2. You are not using `setState` when adding to list in the following lines:

```
 krankheit_name.add(doc.data()["name"]);
 krankheit_beschreibung.add(doc.data()["beschreibung"]);
```

**Two suggestions.**

1. It is not recommended to call future function inside `build()`.You can consider calling it in the `initState()` function.
2. And use the `futureBuilder` to attain your desired function.